Given $9$ permutations of length $20$, we sum up the values for each position in every permutation, what is the maximum value for the minimum sum
You're given 9 permutations of length 20, for each position $i$, we sum up the values of $p_i$ for each permutation, let it be $c_i$, then we sort the $c$ array in ascending order:  $$c_1 \le c_2 \le c_3 \le \cdots \le c_{20}$$
$c_i$ is the sum of $p_i$ for all permutations.
If for the position i, in all permutations, $\max(p_i) - \min(p_i) \le 3$ (i.e. $p_x$ can't be $1$ in one permutation and $5$ in another one), holds, what is the maximum value for $c_1$
Edit:
So I've proved that the maximum value is $\le 33$, and I have an example for $c_1 = 21$.
Proof for 33: assume there exists an example where $c_1 \gt 33$, it's obvious the $c_1$ doesn't consist of $9$ ones in the permutations, so there exists at least one position with containing the value $1$ in at least one the permutations, let be in the position $i$, the maximum value of $c_i$ is $1 + 8 \cdot 4$ which is $33$, so $c_i \lt c_1$, contradiction.
but I've been stuck on it for a few hours to improve this bound but, Guess I'm weak :(
Regards.

What have you tried so far?

Edited it @BoweiTang

What is $p_i$ ?

You can only have four permutations that include a $1$.  If there were $5$, each of them would have to consist of numbers $1-4$ but there are only $80$ of those, not $100$.  If there are four of them, they will use up all the numbers $1-4$.  Then $c_1+c_2+c_3+c_4=90$ and you should be able to get $22,22,23,23$ from this.  You might do a little better if you put all the $1$s into only three permutations but then the ones that have $2$s have to have nothing larger than $5$ and you may run out of small numbers again.

Via integer linear programming, the maximum turns out to be $24$ as follows:
  1 2 3 4 5 6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 
1 2 3 1 4 5 6 10 11  7  8  9 12 13 15 14 16 17 18 19 20 
2 2 3 1 4 5 6  7 11 10  9  8 12 13 14 16 15 18 17 19 20 
3 2 1 4 3 5 6  7  8  9 11 10 12 13 16 14 17 15 18 19 20 
4 5 1 4 3 2 6 10  8  7  9 11 13 12 14 15 16 17 19 20 18 
5 2 3 4 1 5 6  7  8 10  9 11 12 13 14 17 15 16 18 19 20 
6 2 3 4 1 5 6  7  8 10  9 11 13 12 15 14 16 18 17 19 20 
7 2 3 4 1 5 6  7  8 10 11  9 12 13 15 14 16 18 20 17 19 
8 5 3 1 4 2 6  7  8 10 11  9 12 13 14 15 18 16 17 20 19 
9 2 4 1 3 5 6  7 11 10  8  9 12 13 14 15 16 18 20 19 17 


By request, here is SAS code:
proc optmodel;
   num numRows = 9;
   num numCols = 20;
   set ROWS = 1..numRows;
   set COLS = 1..numCols;
   set VALUES = 1..numCols;

   var X {ROWS, COLS, VALUES} binary;

   impvar P {i in ROWS, j in COLS} = sum {k in VALUES} k * X[i,j,k];
   impvar C {j in COLS} = sum {i in ROWS} P[i,j];

   max Objective = min {j in COLS} C[j];

   con OneValue {i in ROWS, j in COLS}:
      sum {k in VALUES} X[i,j,k] = 1;
   con Alldiff {i in ROWS, k in VALUES}:
      sum {j in COLS} X[i,j,k] = 1;
   con WithinThree {j in COLS}:
      max {i in ROWS} P[i,j] - min {i in ROWS} P[i,j] <= 3;

   solve linearize;

   print P;
   print C;
quit;


Hello, would you mind sharing ur code
